# Get nearest index value of a given value from a List of Double numbers

Tags: java, android, list

I have a `List` of `Doubles`:

```
List<Double>  aList = Arrays.asList(100.33,300.99,600.0,900.44,1200.88,1500.15);
```

I need to find the nearest value of a given value from that list. I tried below solution that comes from another answer of SO, but so far this doesn't work, the `idx` is always 0.

Below is the solution that I was checking with:

```
private Double chekcer() {
    int myNumber = 900;
    double distance = (aList.get(0)- myNumber);
    int idx = 0;
    for (int c = 1; c < aList.size(); c++) {
        double cdistance = (aList.get(c) - myNumber);
        if (cdistance < distance) {
            idx = c;
            distance = cdistance;
        }
    }
    Log("",...);
    return aList.get(idx);
}
```

Comment: to find out a `nearest` value, you should calculate the absolute difference but not just minus them, you can change `double distance = (aList.get(0)- myNumber);` to `double distance = Math.abs(aList.get(0)- myNumber);` and `double cdistance = (aList.get(c) - myNumber);` to `double cdistance = Math.abs(aList.get(c) - myNumber);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the absolute value of the difference and it maybe above or below 0

try

```
private Double chekcer() {
  int myNumber = 900;
  double distance = Math.abs(aList.get(0)- myNumber);
  int idx = 0;
  for (int c = 1; c < aList.size(); c++) {
    double cdistance = Math.abs(aList.get(c) - myNumber);
    if (cdistance < distance) {
        idx = c;
        distance = cdistance;
    }
  }
  Log("",...);
  return aList.get(idx);
}
```

**edit**

This is my whole code,

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    System.out.println(chekcer());
}

private static Double chekcer() {
      List<Double>  aList = Arrays.asList(100.33,300.99,600.0,900.44,1200.88,1500.15);
      int myNumber = 900;
      double distance = Math.abs(aList.get(0)- myNumber);
      int idx = 0;
      for (int c = 1; c < aList.size(); c++) {
        double cdistance = Math.abs(aList.get(c) - myNumber);
        if (cdistance < distance) {
            idx = c;
            distance = cdistance;
        }
      }
      return aList.get(idx);
    }
```

**output**

900.44

Comment: Nop. same result.

Comment: I get he value `900.44`, getting `zero` is not even an option

Comment: I dont know why its diffrent result but this is the photo of result I'm getting. <link removed>

Comment: because you missed `double distance = Math.abs(aList.get(0)- myNumber);`

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:
You may find the code to be useful

```
    private static Double chekcer() {
      List<Double>  aList = Arrays.asList(100.33,300.99,600.0,900.44,1200.88,1500.15);
      int myNumber = 900;
      return aList.stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> Math.abs(i - myNumber))).orElse(null);     
     }
```